# Custom List View with custom list item which has Spinner

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I'm implementing a custom list view with custom list item which has spinner and text box. And I want to save selected value of spinner using `onItemSelected()` in list item of list view, but I don't have any idea to find a list item which holds the spinner that user is handling. How can I get this, can anyone help this?

Below is my codes in list view adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;

    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.view1 = (Spinner) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        viewHolder.view2 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view2);

        viewHolder.view1.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.view2.setFocusable(false);

        viewHolder.view1.setAdapter(view1Adapter);
        viewHolder.view1.setPrompt("Select");
        viewHolder.view1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedId = spinnerItemList.get(position).id;
                // todo : need to find a way to get list item of list view, which has this spinner, like the position of getView().
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        listItemView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    CustomListItem item = listViewItemList.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = listItemView.getTag();
    viewHolder.view1.setSelection(item.view1Value);
    viewHolder.view2.setText(String.valueOf(item.view2Value));

    return listItemView;
}
```

Comment: @Loc Yes, it doesn't need to be instance, index of CustomListItem would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting what I've found as an answer for someone who would have same issue with me. Actually I saw this idea from Loc's answer, but he deleted his answer somehow. Maybe there might be a serious problem in this solution. Anyway this works for me now.

I used setTag() and getTag() to get CustomListItem. Please see below codes.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View listItemView = convertView;

  if (listItemView == null) {
    listItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.view1 = (Spinner) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view1);
    viewHolder.view2 = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view2);

    viewHolder.view1.setFocusable(false);
    viewHolder.view2.setFocusable(false);

    viewHolder.view1.setAdapter(view1Adapter);
    viewHolder.view1.setPrompt("Select");
    viewHolder.view1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedId = spinnerItemList.get(position).id;
            // todo : need to find a way to get list item of list view, which has this spinner, like the position of getView().
            CustomListItem item = (CustomListItem)parent.getTag();
            item.view1Value = selectedId;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    listItemView.setTag(viewHolder);
  }

  CustomListItem item = listViewItemList.get(position);
  ViewHolder viewHolder = listItemView.getTag();
  viewHolder.view1.setSelection(item.view1Value);
  viewHolder.view.setTag(item);
  viewHolder.view2.setText(String.valueOf(item.view2Value));

  return listItemView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to handle the onItemSelected of the spinner inside the adapter try this:

//pass the context of the activity / fragment to the adapter

```
context.saveSelectedValue(selectedId);
```

//save the selected it within the activity / fragment

```
public void saveSelectedValue(String id){
   //code to save
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I need to know the index of CustomListItem too. And the way to get it is what I really want to know.